# Laravel BusServieProvider

Tags: php, laravel, api, ubuntu-16.04

i've been struggling with this error for some time now. am having this error below in my laravel API when i push to live server, but the same codebase is working perfectly and dispatches every mail in the controller.

exception:

> ParseError"
> file: "/var/www/server.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/BusServiceProvider.php"
> line: 51
> message: "syntax error, unexpected ')'"

This is the snippet of the code in my controller that fails.

```
public function approve_results($id){

    $user = (Auth::user()->firstname . ' ' . Auth::user()->lastname);

    $pass = DB::table('passengers')->select('*')->where('id', $id)
                ->where('deleted_at', NULL)
                ->first();

    $current_timestamp = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

    if($pass->approval_status != 'PENDING'){
        return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Results already approved',
                'errorCode' => 401
            ]);
    } else {

        DB::table('passengers')->select('*')
                ->where('unique_number', $pass->unique_number)
                ->update(['approval_status' => 'APPROVED', 'approved_by' => $user, 'approval_date' => $current_timestamp]);


        $getphonecode = Country::where('nicename', '=', $pass->nationality)->first();
        $callcode = $getphonecode->phonecode;
        if($pass->telephone)
            $query_checker = '+233';

        $pass_phone = $pass->telephone;

        if (strpos($pass_phone, $query_checker) !== false ){
            $phone = ltrim($pass->telephone, '+');
        }else{
            $phone = ($callcode . ltrim($pass->telephone, '0'));
        }

        $status         = $pass->status;
        $name           = $pass->firstname . ' ' . $pass->lastname;
        $emailAddress   = $pass->email;
        $dob            = $pass->dob;
        $nationality    = $pass->nationality;
        $address        = $pass->address;
        $gender         = $pass->sex;
        $test_type      = $pass->test_type;
        $sample_collection_date = $pass->sample_collection_date;
        $sample_collection_time = $pass->sample_collection_time;
        $status         = $pass->status;
        $unique_number  = $pass->unique_number;
        $traveller      = $pass->travelling_status;
        $passport       = $pass->passport_number;
        $test_date      = $pass->test_date;
        $lab_id         = $pass->lab_id;
        $sormas_id      = $pass->sormas_id;
        $specimen_type  = $pass->specimen_type;

        if(strpos($phone, '233') != false ){
            // SendResultsViaSMS::dispatch($phone, $status, $name, $callcode, $uniqueNumber);
            Mail::to($emailAddress)->queue(new Results(strtoupper($status), $name, $passport ,$test_date,
            $lab_id, $sormas_id, $dob, $test_type, $specimen_type, $sample_collection_date, $sample_collection_time));
        }else{
            SendResultsViaSMS::dispatch($phone, $status, $name, $callcode, $unique_number);
            Mail::to($emailAddress)->queue(new Results(strtoupper($status), $name, $passport ,$test_date,
            $lab_id, $sormas_id, $dob, $test_type, $specimen_type, $sample_collection_date, $sample_collection_time));
        }

        return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Results Approved',
                'errorCode' => 201
        ]);
    }

}
```

The Database updates alright but the mail is not sent and it gives me a 500 internal error.
When the database updates, am supposed to recieved and mail is sent. I have to recieve  a 201 error code which i then use in the frontend for routing.

Comment: Which line is #51?

Comment: wrong version of PHP most likely, since it is a syntax error in framework code

Comment: you can update the framework code, since they removed a trailing comma there, or use a newer version of PHP    https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/f22333a7c0bb550a9bc9463f26695c256cbfb10e

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using, and what version of Laravel? This is a Laravel core file, so you should not make updates to it.

Comment: "update the framework code" means to update the framework not edit the code ... sorry for not being specific

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @lagbox and to everyone who commented.
So i was able to fix it by updating the code base, i edited vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/BusServiceProvider.php
and removed the trailing comma on line 51

Comment: no ... don't edit the framework code base ... UPDATE the framework via composer (you don't edit anything in vendor)

Comment: they already made this change in the framework for you, you just need to have a newer version of what ever version you are using ... or use a newer version of PHP

Comment: You really really really don't want to do this, because the next `composer install` or `composer update` will likely blow the changes away.